# Azure AD B2C Branding - get the email, name info from Google+

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

We are implementing Azure AD B2C, part of that is the custom branding.

When you select Google+ (or LinkedIn) and are logged in, you are redirected to a page with the email and name info from Google, when the default branding page is used.
(signup policy, Social account sign-up page )

When we create a custom page as described on the [B2C customize page](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-b2c-reference-ui-customization/), the data from the provider is not shown.

What do we need to change in the html page to get that data?

Comment: We have a workaround now. I used the default branding page, signed in with Google and the Email and Name info is filled in.

I then copied the source of that page and adjusted it a bit (mainly removed the data).

But I did not see yet why this does work. So I am still curious.

Answer (score 0):

When I complete the wizard in Google+, about adding friends and/or interests, the names are taken from the Google+ account.

And the following element wes needed (although not all our html is taken with this element).