# Oauth Google, Azure B2C - The name is not always taken from Google

Tags: oauth, google-oauth, azure-ad-b2c

I am implementing Azure AD B2C, with Google.

When I login with my personal Google account, on the next page, the email and name is filled in (First-, last and full name).

When I use an another Google (test) account I just created, the name info is not filled in. This happened with several accounts, and I cannot find what causes this. In Google account settings the Full name is shown and visible for everybody.

Note: 
I use a custom branding page which I made by copying the source from the default branding page. I did not find how to do that from scratch, as in this post: [Azure AD B2C Branding - get the email, name info from Google+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35135999/azure-ad-b2c-branding-get-the-email-name-info-from-google)

I know that this is (most probably) not a coding issue, but a Google account issue, but I figured this is the best place to get the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I complete the wizard in Google+, about adding friends and/or interests, the names are taken from the Google+ account.